# colorbox ajax example on Mac Chrome has flicker when closing

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm checking out the colorBox examples in Chrome (Mac, 19.0.1084.46 on a MB Pro)
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

Flash / Video (Ajax/Embedded)
Flash / Video (Iframe/Direct Link To YouTube)

Sometimes when I close the modal it disappears, but then flashes back on and disappears. It's just a split second and only happens in Chrome. I also see some flickering in the overlay for those samples. Anyone else see this? Any ideas for fixing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but I was struggling  with the same flickering issue today. Here is what helped me: hiding the modal window content with `onCleanup` callback (it happens right before the modal closes).

Answer (score 0):

For me, It seems to work perfectly fine. I do not see the modal appear and disappear in a split second after i close it, in chrome.

My chrome Version 19.0.1084.52